# asp.net ajax file upload causes full page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I'm trying to test something for a component I'm building. Here's what I'm trying to do.

1. Upload file to a server without posting back or refreshing the page.
2. I decided to use ajaxfileupload control.
3. The file uploads but after the SaveAs Method is called in the backend, the whole page is getting refreshed for some weird reason.

Here's the code .aspx Page:

`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
                <%= DateTime.Now %>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
                    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload runat="server" 
                      ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete" />
       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`

Here's the backend Code:
`

```
protected void UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
  AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/" + e.FileName));
}
```

`

The DateTime.Now block is to keep track of refreshes/postbacks.

Comment: Use trigger in update pane.

Comment: You can use HTML5 features which allow to upload file via javascript

Comment: @VijayRaheja: I did try with formData() to send files which worked good, but i had the same issue with respect to the entire page refreshing immediately after writing to the disk.

Comment: Use <input type="file" in html, then this will not occur.